# Finding a tricky limit using intergral sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the limit, interpreting this as as the limit of the integral sum of a suitably chosen function.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)... (n+n)}.$$

A hint that has been given: find the logarithm of equation and then find a limit of logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

Proceed by simplifying the given expression:
$$s = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n+i}{n}\right)^{1/n}\\
\ln(s) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right) \right) \\ = \int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+x)dx$$

Comment: $ln(\frac{27}{4}) - 1 $

Comment: What should i do with it next?

Comment: @M.Smithy: Write that the **correct** limit is $$\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x)\,dx = \frac{4}{e}.$$

Comment: Oops such a silly error. corrected it.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but can you explain, where did you get this equality? I'm a bit confused..  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right) \right) \\ = \int_{0}^{1} \ln(1+x)dx$$

Comment: @M.Smithy Refer this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum